# Class.forName() caching

Tags: java, performance, reflection

In one of my applications I am using the following:

```
public void calculate (String className)
{
  ... 
  Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
  ...
}
```

This function is called several times / second.
There are about 10 possible class names.
And while I do realize there is some internal caching inside this function,
I think this caching is only available on native level.

For this reason I am starting to wonder if I should add my own caching.

```
private static Map<String,Class> classMap;

public void calculate (String className)
{
  ... 
  Class clazz = classMap.get(className);
  if (clazz == null) 
  {
      clazz = Class.forName(className);
      if (classMap == null) classMap = new HashMap<String, Class>(40);
      classMap.put(className, clazz);
  }
  ...
}
```

Will this be a performance gain or does it really make no difference ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I can think of one way to find out...

Comment: Did you profile your application? Does it prove to be a bottelneck? If not, I'd not implement a cache until it is needed.

Comment: Do you see BLOCKED threads in a thread dump? I see them while profiling my app, so I think Class.forName() is worth caching.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wrote a little script to calculate the execution time of both functions.

This is the Main class that I used.

```
public class Benchmark
{
  public static void main(String... pArgs)
  {
    // prepare all data as much as possible.
    // we don't want to do this while the clock is running.
    Class[] classes = {Object.class, Integer.class, String.class, Short.class, Long.class, Double.class,
                       Float.class, Boolean.class, Character.class, Byte.class};
    int cycles = 1000000;
    String[] classNames = new String[cycles];
    for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++) 
    {
      classNames[i] = classes[i % classes.length].getName();
    }

    // THERE ARE 2 IMPLEMENTATIONS - CLASSIC vs CACHING
    Implementation impl = new Caching();   // or Classic();

    // Start the clocks !
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
    {
      impl.doStuff(classNames[i]);
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // calculate and display result
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(totalTime);
  }
}
```

Here is the classic implementation that uses `Class.forName`

```
  private interface Implementation
  {
    Class doStuff(String clzName);
  }

  private static class Classic implements Implementation
  {
    @Override
    public Class doStuff(String clzName)
    {
      try
      {
        return Class.forName(clzName);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the second implementation that uses a `HashMap` to cache the `Class` objects.

```
  private static class Caching implements Implementation
  {
    private Map<String, Class> cache = new HashMap<String, Class>();

    @Override
    public Class doStuff(String clzName)
    {
      Class clz = cache.get(clzName);
      if (clz != null) return clz;
      try
      {
        clz = Class.forName(clzName);
        cache.put(clzName, clz);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
      }
      return clz;
    }
  }
```

**The results:**

- 1100 ms without caching.
- only 15 ms with caching.

**Conclusion:**

- Is it a significant difference --> yes !
- Does it matter for my application --> not at all.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `currentTimeMillis` for benchmarking, and you should include a warm-up period for JIT compilation etc. It probably wouldn't change the results *very* much, but it's worth knowing about. I wouldn't catch the exceptions here, either...

Comment: I've just run the benchmarks myself, and found that if the classes I'm looking for are ones defined by the current classloader (rather than some "core" one) then it's about 10% faster in the slow case... presumably because it's not delegating. Still slower than the caching version, but not as bad.

Comment: Just wondering... what should I use instead of the currentTimeMillis ? I never used it before to be honest, but got it from some other stackoverflow topic. By a warm-up period, you mean a simple Thread.sleep(10000), right ? - Thanks for the comments

Comment: Use `System.nanoTime` for high precision *difference* measuring. (It's a stopwatch rather than a clock, if you see what I mean.) And no, sleeping won't help for warmup - you want to exercise the code that you'll be timing, so that the JIT has the opportunity to optimize it before you measure. There's a good library somewhere that helps with all of this, but I can't remember the name right now...

Answer (score 14):

> Will this be a performance gain or does it really make no difference?

I would be astonished if it made a significant difference - and if you're only calling it "several times per second" (rather than, say, a million) it's really not worth optimizing.

You should *at least* try this in isolation in a benchmark before committing to this more complicated design. I would strongly expect `Class.forName` to be caching this anyway, and adding more complexity into your app does no good.

Comment: +1 I suspect a micro-benchmark would show a difference but in a real application, I would be very surprised if it did.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jon. I took your advice and did some benchmarking, and added the results here as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`Class.forName()` does two things:

1. it fetches a loaded class from the classloader
2. if no such class is found, it tries to load it.

Part #1 is pretty quick. #2 is where the real work starts (where the JVM might hit the hard disk or even the network, depending on the classloader). And if you pass the same parameters in, then all but the first invocations will never get to step #2.

So no: it's *probably* not worth optimizing.

Comment: But doesn't this mean that if the parent class loader is garbage collected then #2 might be run every time?

Comment: What do you mean by parent class loading being garbage collected? A parent classloader P of a classloader C can't be garbage-collected until both P & C are eligible for garbage collection. In other words: P can't be garbage collected from "under C".

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was if both the loaded class and the class loader are garbage collected between each use then #2 would be used every time and performance always be impacted.

Comment: @Jeppz: yes, that is correct, but also extremely unlikely. Classloaders are notoriously hard to become eligible for garbage collection (since every single instance of a class they loaded keeps them referenced), so the chance of this happening "accidentally" are rather slim.

Answer (score 2):

No you shouldn't. Class.forName will not load the same class twice but will try to find the class among the loaded classes. It's done at native level and supposed to be very efficient.